# implementing the WP7 chatting style

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to design a chatting app, I want the sender/receiver's text to be shown inside these text balloons that's in the native messages app in WP7.

I can put each conversation in a textblock and color it like the current used theme, but still it won't have the pointy thing of the balloon here:

[image: see pointy balloons]

So how can I implement this to my app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out these links:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/07/a-wp7-conversation-view/

http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Recreating-the-Windows-Phone-7-message-e2809cbubblee2809d-style-in-Silverlight.aspx

They should have all you need to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Shapes and Basic Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).

What you want to do , is to define two shapes (one being a mirror of the other), with the "triangle" popping out as part of the polygon.

I'll recommend a tool like Expression Design or Expression Blend for creating the polygon.

Comment: hmm, or just put an image of the baloon beneath a textblock with invisible borders? would that work?

Comment: @SherifMaherEaid: You probably wouldn't want to do that, as using a (raster) image in a vector graphics toolkit such as silverlight is generally discouraged, except in cases where the resolution of the image is sufficient enough to maintain sufficient dpi independence.

Comment: @SherifMaherEaid don't go for the easy solution, just because you can't be bothered spending 5 minutes learning ;-)